# Parsing JSON output in Robot framework [TypeError: expected string or buffer]

Tags: python, json, dictionary, robotframework, jsonparser

I have a JSON output like this:

```
{
  "output": {
    "ParentKey": {
      "key": "9b92e663a66c0cc1",
      "id": "uid=26"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the content of key, that is: **9b92e663a66c0cc1**

Lets say ${output} has this JSON content/data..

This is the code I tried:

```
${values}=    Evaluate    json.loads($output)    json
${response}    Evaluate      json.loads($values['output']['ParentKey'])  json
${key}  set variable  ${response['ParentKey']['key']}
[Return]  ${key}
```

I'm using older Robot (less than v3.2)

However, I'm getting an error like this

> Evaluating expression 'json .loads (RF_VAR_values
> ['output']['ParentKey'])' failed: TypeError: expected string
> or buffer

How do I fetch the key without getting above error?

Thank you!!!

Comment: second json.loads & evaluates is unnecessary because once you have loaded the json into ${valiues}, values is already dictionary, not a string ..  most likely you can remove the second line and change the tried line "response" to "values"

Comment: I think that doesn't work, 'output' becomes key and rest all content in the file become single value to 'output' key. So I think you cannot directly access the values!

Comment: Did you try ? answer highlights this and does work for me at least

Comment: This data is different from the data in your previous question. @rasjani is correct, you don't need to call `json.loads` twice.

Comment: It worked, Thank you both!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*** Settings ***
*** Variables ***

${our_json}   { "output": { "ParentKey": { "key": "9b92e663a66c0cc1", "id": "uid=26" } } }


*** Test Case ***
Test JSON
  ${values}=    Evaluate    json.loads($our_json)    json
  Log To Console    ${values}
  ${key}  set variable  ${values['output']['ParentKey']['key']}
  Log To Console   OUR KEY: ${key}
```

outputs:

```
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
Test JSON                                                             .{'output': {'ParentKey': {'key': '9b92e663a66c0cc1', 'id': 'uid=26'}}}
..OUR KEY: 9b92e663a66c0cc1
Test JSON                                                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```